# What to do with too many old bike parts and frames to count

Tags: frames

The side of our house is filled with old bike frames, parts, accessories, etc. - Once I hose them off and clean them up, I would LOVE to get rid of them.  Where's a good place to sell them?

Comment: Well, I'd be careful with hosing them off. Places where bearings are located don't like getting water in them. As for places, that depends where you are -- ebay, velobase, forums, craigslist, whatever. That being said, you may want to get someone knowledgeable about bikes to note the value of what you're selling -- a lot of stuff is just junk and is more likely easier to recycle.

Comment: Welcome to [bicycles.se] @Cheryl. Good to see you've taken the [tour], the next step would be to browse [ask]. You'll see why we think your question is off topic here. Batman made some good suggestions, but also someone knowledge might spot which items have special value.

Comment: Scrap man and Ebay are your two go-tos for this.  take time and clean it all up though.

Comment: Please note that for many of us on this SE, there is no such thing as too many bike parts. Our spouses may disagree. :)

Answer (score 5):

I work two afternoons a week with a group called "Cycle it Forward", a local organization which rehabs old bikes and makes them available to Christmas Anonymous and other charities in the community.

You should check around your community to see if there is some similar organization to which you can donate at least some of your trove.

(But be aware that random frames and bike parts, unless of exceptional quality, are worth more as metal scrap than as bikes.)

Comment: There are also bike co-ops in some areas for donation.

Answer (score 1):

What is your main motivation - make money or have them gone?

To get rid of them, our local waste transfer station has a recycle centre that sells old usable bikes (about $5 a bike, $10 for a good one and donate profits to charity) or they go to metal recyclers.  We also have a bike coop that will take bikes and bits, make going bikes and donate them to kids (or adults) who cannot afford bikes.

If the bikes are too good to give away and worth money to someone (its not about what you think they are worth, its what they think), the likes of Ebay, Craigs list are good, but for cheap bikes local avenues are better.